# grammatical errors on privacy page linked from security web page

Tags: web-service, account-security, scam

My Employer has sent me a link related to setting up security questions for Microsoft Azure account. I clicked on the privacy link from that page which sent me to the following page:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/privacystatement/OnlineServices/Default.aspx

This page has grammatical errors in it.  For example, the sentence:

```
Customer Data will be used only to provide customer the Online Services
  including purposes compatible with providing those services
```

Microsoft and many other on-line sites have said that grammatical errors are a red flag indicating a scam to get information from you. How do I determine if I can trust a page that has errors or links to others with errors on it?

The fact that the page is a Microsoft URL doesn't preclude an attacker who has altered one of their webpages, so the fact that it is at www.microsoft.com is not sufficient to allow trust.

Basically, my question boils down to **"If a major U.S. company can't reliably write good English grammar when communicating, how is bad grammar a valid flag for scammers?"**

Comment: It isn't. Bad grammar just gets rid of the more security conscious people, acting as an effective filter for n00bs

Comment: Where's the bad grammar? It's perfectly in line with typical legal language. Especially when articles are dropped.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't actually seem to be grammatically incorrect, as it's a legal document.

For instance:

> Except as customer directs, Microsoft will not provide any third
>   party:  (1) direct, indirect, blanket or unfettered access to Customer
>   Data; (2) the platform encryption keys used to secure Customer Data or
>   the ability to break such encryption; or (3) any kind of access to
>   Customer Data if Microsoft is aware that such data is used for
>   purposes other than those stated in the request.

One of the benefits of living in a country with two official languages is that you can determine low-level, unsophisticated fakes by the spelling, grammar, and punctuation of both languages. The same holds for singular language countries and their products.

Microsoft indicates on it's *Piracy - How To Tell* page for software:

> When viewing packaging, simple things like spelling errors, blurry
>   text and images, or poor print quality can help you identify
>   counterfeit software. Incorrect logos and photos that don’t quite
>   correspond to the product you’re purchasing can also **provide clues**
>   that something isn’t quite right.

This doesn't mean using spelling/grammar/punctuation is fool proof, but a way to **indicate** to the end user that **they probably should** investigate the reputability of the vendor/seller further.

Web Links:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/howtotell/Software.aspx?tab=PackagedSoftwareTab

Answer (score 0):

I think the grammar is a bit off. But I also agree it is perfectly in line with typical legal language.

Regardless. The reliability of bad grammar as a “valid flag for scammers” depends on all the other flags, bad grammar should not be used as the exclusive method of detection, common sense needs to be applied as well.

It is not uncommon for phishing attempts to be made by individuals who use English as a second language, therefore in many instances the grammar can be incorrect and seem off.

But this is just a single indicator, some phishing attempts will have perfect grammar and some legitimate emails or websites will have bad grammar.

Bad grammar can help initial detection of something that looks suspicious, it should be used with other common indicators of suspicious webpages, phishing emails etc. Indicators such as suspicious URL’s, unsolicited communications (especially those that ask for personal information), communications that try and pressure you to act quickly or promise something that looks too good to be true and so on.